# Is There Macdeployqt for QT Command Line Executable Binary Without App Bundle?

Tags: macos, qt, deployment

I'm trying to build a command line tool on Mac that doesn't result in .app bundle.

When I run make release, it just gives an executable file since it's a command line tool for terminal.

I understand that macdeployqt lets you package all the necessary files for .app to run without qt installed on another machine.

Is there similar tool for just binary executable?

When I pass the executable to macdeployqt, I get "ERROR: Could not find bundle binary for ...".

Comment: Do you mean, you want a *statically linked* binary executable, which includes everything in it?

Comment: Yes, exactly!!!

Answer (score 0):

`macdeployqt` is run against an existing `.app` bundle and handles most of the library collection and `install_name_tool` business to make the bundle deployable.  Even if you were to utilize this tool, you would end up customizing the binary's install_name info manually to suit your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/SCG82/macdylibbundler will bundle an app and fix up the install names/rpaths. Disclaimer: I'm the developer.